# REST API Over HTTP2: I need to parse the binary response?

Tags: parsing, response, httpresponse, http2

I have one doubt respect REST API response and HTTP2.

If HTTP2 has a binary frame for the TCP layer. Our application should not have to parse this binary response? Or its transparent for all the kinds of format response possible (assets, json, plain text,etc) ?

Comment: No, you should be fine. Here is a tutorial in Spanish about how to use software that will convert HTTP/2 API requests to normal HTTP/1 requests: https://www.shimmercat.com/es/info/articles/getting-started/ and then https://www.shimmercat.com/es/info/articles/structuring-apps/ . If you find something confusing leave your comments in the articles!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary transport will be completely transparent to your code. It only effects how files get from one end to the other.